# What's wrong with this selector declaration?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I expect this to work based on the docs here: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocSelectors.html

```
SEL sel = @selector(loadMapType:[ms uniqueTilecacheKey]);

"error: expected ')' before '[' token"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[ms uniqueTilecacheKey]
```

That's what's wrong. A selector is essentially just a method signature, so you don't pass it parameters.

It should instead look like

```
SEL sel = @selector(loadMapType:);
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler gave you the answer.  It was expecting the close parenthesis to complete the @selector() directive, not a message expression.  Think of the selector as the name of the method.